# use a character date string as a date in data step

Tags: date, sas, sas-macro, datastep

I have the following two macro variables:

```
%let start_date = 29MAY2014;
%let end_date = 15JUL2014;
```

I would like to create a dataset which is a series of dates between these (inclusive.) I cannot change the input format of the macro variables `&start_date` and `&end_date`.

I have tried many variations of the following, but SAS spits out an error for each:

```
data base_dates;
   do date = put("&start_date",date9.) to put("&end_date",date9.);
      output;
   end;
   format date date11.;
run;
```

Any help in this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use them as date literals, enclose in quotes and add a d at the end.

```
Do date = "&start_date"d to "&end_date"d;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was simple; input() instead of put()

```
data base_dates;
do date = input("&start_date",date9.) to input("&end_date",date9.);
output;
end;
format date date11.;
run;
```

Comment: @Reeza's solution should the preferred way.